# Apple: In App Purchase Subscriptions Server Notifications view past history

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am implementing IAP into my app and have started using the server notifications. I am wondering is apple offer sometype of dashboard where I can see the history of past attempted notifications just like google and stripes webhook dashboards?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "past attempted notification"? Notifications that weren't handled by your server?

Comment: Yes and also sent to my server. Like with Stripe and Google you can view all notificaiton online that was sent to the service

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. The only thing you can do is calling the `/verifyReceipt` API for each one of your receipts to get their complete history.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case I am wondering, if after purchase from the app, the initial call to my DB fails from the device with the purchase information etc (and information that allows me to link to the userid in my db) then how would you adivse I make the link in future considering apple IAP does not allow custom/ developer payloads like google and stripe?

Comment: You can add a "restore" button on your Paywall (and ideally in your settings): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/restoring_purchased_products

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any dashboard to see notifications, but If a notification failed because your server didn't handle it or returned a status code other than 200, then Apple retires 3 times.

> If the App Store server doesn’t receive a 200 response from your server after the initial notification attempt, it retries [...] at 6, 24, and 48 hours after its initial attempt.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/your_server